# implementacion de una vista en SQL en base a una consulta

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

Tengo un error que no sé cómo solucionar.

Quiero implementar una vista, erp.v_imp_pend sobre la consulta que muestro a continuación:

código de la CONSULTA:

```
SELECT c.co_code, c.co_name, p.cust_no, p.cust_name, i.iva_amount, i.tot_amount
FROM (erp.tb_invoice AS i JOIN erp.tb_company AS c ON c.co_code = i.co_code)   
JOIN erp.tb_customer AS p ON c.co_code = i.co_code
WHERE i.payed = 'N'
ORDER BY c.co_name, c.co_code DESC;
```

En esta consulta lo que quiero hacer es proporcionar una lista de facturas pendientes por cobrar.

Muestro el código de la VISTA que he planteado:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW erp.v_imp_pendiente AS
SELECT * 
FROM (erp.tb_invoice AS i JOIN erp.tb_company AS c ON c.co_code = i.co_code)   
JOIN erp.tb_customer AS p ON c.co_code = i.co_code 
WHERE i.payed = 'N'
ORDER BY c.co_name, c.co_code DESC
WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

El error mostrado es el siguiente:

```
ERROR:  WITH CHECK OPTION sólo puede usarse en vistas automáticamente actualizables
HINT:  Las vistas que no extraen desde una única tabla o vista no son automáticamente actualizables.
```

Las tablas a emplear son las que muestro:

| tb_invoice | tb_company | tb_customer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Code – foreign key company | Code – primary key | Cust_no |
| Invoice_id – primary key | Name | cust_name |
| Invoice_no | Address | cust_cif |
| Cust_no - foreign key customer | City | Last_updated_by |
| Site_id- foreign key site | Country | Last_update_date |
| Payednet_amount | Last_updated_by |  |
| Iva_amount | Last_update_date |  |
| Tot_amount |  |  |
| Last_updated_by |  |  |
| Last_update_date |  |  |

No soy capaz de entender qué está fallando. Solo puedo emplear una tabla para hacer la vista actualizable? (pregunta en base al HINT)

Gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: Y yo veo claro el error.. dice que si tu vista tiene un join, no podes usar esa opcion... habria que ver que dice la documentacion en ese caso...

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr:** Quítale el WITH CHECK OPTION. Te dio pereza crear la vista sin eso y probar. Si lo pruebas en tu vista que tiene un JOIN, **no te va a dejar hacer insert ni update** porque esa es la configuración de la BD para esas vistas que usan JOIN. NO USES WITH CHECK OPTION y ya.

**Versión larga:**

El primer camino siempre debe ser leer ese log y leer la documentación oficial.

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html), es claro el conjunto de condiciones para una vista actualizable:

```
The view must have exactly one entry in its FROM list, which must be a table or another updatable view.

The view definition must not contain WITH, DISTINCT, GROUP BY, HAVING, LIMIT, or OFFSET clauses at the top level.

The view definition must not contain set operations (UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT) at the top level.

The view's select list must not contain any aggregates, window functions or set-returning functions.
```

Que en español de la calle se traduce más o menos como:

```
La vista debe tener exactamente UNA entrada en su cláusula FROM, que debe ser una tabla u otra vista actualizable.

La definición de la vista no debe contener cláusulas WITH, DISTINCT, GROUP BY, HAVING, LIMIT u OFFSET en el nivel principal de la consulta (no incluye subconsultas, mejor dicho).

La definición de la vista no debe contener operaciones de conjunto (UNION, INTERSECT o EXCEPT) en el nivel principal.

La lista de campos en el SELECT no debe contener agregados, _window functions_ o funciones-que-retornen-conjuntos.
```

No cumples la primera condición.

Por qué quieres usar WITH CHECK OPTION en este escenario? Efectivamente, esta condición de la vista evita que los usuarios inserten o modifiquen datos directamente en la vista que no puedan verse en ella. Si tienes más de una tabla generando la vista, el motor no es capaz de validar este comportamiento porque ese JOIN no es una vista actualizable.

Edito: para tu segunda pregunta, hay que seguir leyendo la misma documentación oficial. Piensa que son tus colegas tratando de hacer lo mismo que tú, avisándote de los peligros en el camino ;)

Si revisas en la sección de Vistas actualizables, dice

> A more complex view that does not satisfy all these conditions is read-only by default: the system will not allow an insert, update, or delete on the view

Que, de nuevo, en español de la calle en Colombia, es más o menos

> Una vista más compleja que no cumpla con las condiciones es de sólo-lectura por defecto: el sistema (o sea, PostgreSQL) no va a permitir inserciones, actualizaciones o borrados en la vista.

Así pues, por qué no comienzas por probar creando la vista común y corriente e intentando luego tú mismo un insert para ver qué pasa? (Debería salir un error o si no, ¡encontraste un bug!)

Comment: el CHECK OPTION debo usarlo porque como dices, quiero evitar que se inserten valores. Entonces, según lo que indicas, no me bastaría con eliminar el JOIN. Dadas las tablas que tengo que usar para cumplir con la consulta, cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: @IñigoCatalánEchave actualicé la respuesta :)

Comment: si te soy sincero, la documentación y los ejemplos que se indican no me aportan absolutamente nada. Mi problema es que mis conocimientos son mucho menores que todo lo que se trata ahí.

Comment: @icatalan Me parece un poco triste que no intentes leer lo que te estoy comentando. Si estás escribiendo SQL, así sepamos poco, el camino siempre será intentar aprender para hacerlo más fácil la siguiente vez. Edité la respuesta una última vez.

Comment: perdona, el fallo no estaba en el ```WITH CHECK OPTION```. Lo quité tal y como ponía en la información que compartiste (muchas gracias) y seguía fallando. Al sustituir ```*``` por los valores que quería, se solucionó. No entiendo diera fallo así. Colgaré la solución que he aplicado por si sirve en todo caso

Comment: @icatalan Es una mala práctica no indicar campos explícitos en cualquier consulta. Si cambias la tabla, de repente muchas cosas van a dejar de funcionar. Me alegra que te funcionara

Comment: en todo caso, no entiendo que un cambio de ```*``` por los valores explícitos suponga el cambio de error a funcionar. Lo tendré en cuenta porque para un primer intento pensé que era lo más sencillo. Gracias por la aportación tuya también!